# GetFontUnicodeRanges without a window

Tags: winapi, unicode, fonts, delphi-6

Is there a chance to call `GetFontUnicodeRanges` without a window? For example, it could be a Windows service not permitted to interact with desktop.

Currently I am testing this with console application:

```
program UnicodeConsoleOutput;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

var
  NumWritten: DWORD;
  Text: WideString;
  u8s: UTF8String;

procedure Add(AStart, AEnd: Word);
var
  i: Word;
begin
  Text := Text + WideFormat('[%x...%x]:'#13#10, [AStart, AEnd]);
  for i := AStart to AEnd do
    Text := Text + WideChar(i);
  Text := Text + WideString(#13#10#13#10);
end;

//Actually I want to get glyph ranges for "Consolas" font
procedure GetFontRanges();
type
  TRangesArray = array[0..(MaxInt div SizeOf(TWCRange)) - 1] of TWCRange;

  PRangesArray = ^TRangesArray;
const
  ConsoleTitle = '{A46DD332-0D57-4310-B91E-A68957C20429}';
var
  GS: PGlyphSet;
  GSSize: LongWord;
  i: Integer;
  rng: TWCRange;
  hConsole: HWND;
  hDev: HDC;
begin
  //A dirty hack to get console window handle suggested by Microsoft
  SetConsoleTitle(PChar(ConsoleTitle));
  hConsole := FindWindow(nil, PChar(ConsoleTitle));
  
  hDev := GetDC(hConsole);
  try

    GSSize := GetFontUnicodeRanges(hDev, nil);
    GetMem(Pointer(GS), GSSize);
    try
      GS.cbThis := GSSize;
      GS.flAccel := 0;
      GS.cGlyphsSupported := 0;
      GS.cRanges := 0;
      if GetFontUnicodeRanges(hDev, GS) <> 0 then begin
        for i := 0 to GS.cRanges - 1 do begin
          rng := PRangesArray(@GS.ranges)[i];
          Add(Word(rng.wcLow), Word(rng.wcLow) + rng.cGlyphs - 1);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Pointer(GS), GSSize);
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(hConsole, hDev);
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    GetFontRanges();
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    u8s := UTF8Encode(Text);
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(u8s), Length(u8s),
      NumWritten, nil);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: There are Python utilities which can parse and give information about otf (and so ttf) fonts. (and obvaiously there is also a unicode range function. But it is in python.

Comment: Sorry, here is WinAPI and Delphi. Your comment is completely out of context. And I am asking about the specific WinAPI function.

Comment: That's pretty ancient technology. You can tell by the fact that the API doesn't set the calling thread's last error on failure. Presumably, the only reason you need to pass in a DC is because that's how you tell the API which font to use. In that case it *may* be possible to just `CreateDC` one and select your font into it. Alternatively, use a more contemporary API. [DirectWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/direct-write-portal) might have what you're looking for.

Comment: On a side note, rather than using `SetConsoleTitle()`+`FindWindow()`, you can use [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) instead.

Comment: @IInspectable "*the API doesn't set the calling thread's last error on failure*" - most GDI functions don't.

Comment: Yes. GDI *is* ancient. It's been there since 16-bit Windows.

Comment: @Paul, have you tried using memory context created with CreateCompatibleDC(0) ?

Comment: @bunglehead if you do that, you have to `SelectObject()` an `HFONT` into it. Which also means creating a font, such as with `CreateFontIndirect()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, naturally. Somebody has to select it. The question was about interacting with windows, in particular GetDC(hwnd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows GDI, you can create a device context and select a font into it without needing a handle to a window. E.g.,

```
        HDC hdc = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        //CreateCompatibleDC(NULL) also works

        HFONT hFont = CreateFont(
            -20, 0, 0, 0,
            FW_REGULAR,
            FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET,
            OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            DEFAULT_QUALITY,
            DEFAULT_PITCH || FF_DONTCARE,
            L"Arial"
        );

        HFONT oldFont = static_cast<HFONT>(SelectObject(hdc, hFont));
```

Note that GDI text functions use the UTF-16 encoding, and all of them were created before Unicode had assigned any supplementary-plane characters. As a result, functions that take or return lists of characters that are not a string, such as GetFontUnicodeRanges, don't work well for much of Unicode today. [GetFontUnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontunicoderanges) returns a pointer to a [GLYPHSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-glyphset), which has an array of [WCRANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-wcrange) structs. That has a single WCHAR to represent a Unicode character. As a result, GetFontUnicodeRanges has no way to report any Unicode supplementary-plane characters. In some fonts, that might be the majority of characters supported in the font.

In this regard, GDI is not just ancient, but also obsolete. For what you're doing, DirectWrite is a better option: all of its APIs support all Unicode characters.

The DWrite method you want is [IDWriteFontFace1::GetUnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_1/nf-dwrite_1-idwritefontface1-getunicoderanges). Many DWrite APIs, including this, can be used without a window or even a device context. You'll probably want to obtain the IDWriteFontFace1 object by calling [IDWriteFont::CreateFontFace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefont-createfontface), [IDWriteFactory::CreateFontFace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefactory-createfontface) or [IDWriteFontFaceReference::CreateFontFace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/nf-dwrite_3-idwritefontfacereference-createfontface) depending upon the source of the font you're interested in—could be an installed font, a custom font set, a memory blob, or a font file.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for Windows 7 is my target platform. I have no plans to upgrade to Windows 8/10/11 just in order to use IDWriteFontFace1.

Comment: You get DirectWrite with the [Platform Update for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36805) if you need to stay on Windows 7.