# Is there a way to enumerate the individual CHARACTERS in a True Type Font file(TTF)?

Tags: vb.net, truetype

I'm trying to figure out how to enumerate ALL of the characters in a True Type Font.

I have a TTF font - "Pangolin" which is comprised of the COMPONENTS of Japanese Kanji, NOT the Kanji themselves. These are the elements that make up kanji...

I believe it was created based on a basic ASCII "abcdefABCDEF123" etc., as I can create a text file using the above alpha numeric characters, change the font to Pangolin and I see the individual components displayed as kanji bushuu in the same order as what is displayed by the Windows settings Font control, but I need to see ALL of the characters.

I'm sure this is doable...

???

Comment: Are you looking for an app to show you the characters, or you want an API you can call from VB.Net?

Comment: Yes at a minimum I'd like to see ALL of the characters. Of course if there is an API I could use...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use utilities like [BabelMap](https://babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) or [ViewGlyph](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ViewGlyph_home) to see all of the characters in a font.

For APIs, [IDWriteFontFace1::GetUnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_1/nf-dwrite_1-idwritefontface1-getunicoderanges) is recommended. There's also the legacy GDI API [GetFontUnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontunicoderanges), but that is limited in that it can't report when a font supports characters beyond the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383977/getfontunicoderanges-without-a-window/70395358?noredirect=1#comment124449683_70395358) for more discussion of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the info.

I ended up downloading a few "FontViewer" utilities and it turns out that all I needed was a text file with all 256 of the ASCII codes, not just the alpha numerics.

Changing the font type then provided the mapping to the characters I needed to see.